Is there any 4-manifold which is known to have a unique smooth structure?
A well-known problem in 4-manifold topology is the smooth Poincaré conjecture, which states whether any smooth manifold homeomorphic to S⁴ is actually diffeomorphic to S⁴, that is, whether S⁴ has a unique smooth structure. Is there any 4-manifold which is actually known to have a unique smooth structure?

I think it is an open problem. For all we know, every nonempty smoothable 4-manifold has infinitely many pairwise nondiffeomorphic smooth structures.

That was my takeaway too from the research I did for the last few days, but I was unable to find any source confirming that it is an open problem and thought that maybe I'd missed something.

maybe math.overflow is better suited for this question

what is the difference to this site?

This is Problem 4.86 (compact case) and 4.87 on Kirby's list. I am quite sure that both are still open. There is a new problem list in low dimensional topology that is supposed to appear soon, if you want "a source."

thank you, that answers my question!

To remove this from the "unanswered" list: As far as I know, it is still an open problem. It appears on Kirby's 1995 problem list,
"Problems in Low-Dimensional Topology", problems 4.86 (compact manifolds) and 4.87 (noncompact manifolds).
An update on the problem list is supposed to appear soon, see here, if one wants a confirmation of the current status. A resolution of this problem would require new ideas and invariants.
